# setTimeout javascript function 'detonator timer with delay'

Tags: javascript

Write a function detonatorTimer(delay) that outputs a number to the console every second, starting with delay (integer) and ending with 'Happy New Year!' instead of 0. By setTimeout. There are errors in the code, 0 and the text is output twice.

```
function detonatorTimer(delay) {
    console.log(delay);
        if (delay > 0) {
            delay --;
            setTimeout(detonatorTimer, 1000, delay);
        }if(delay === 0) {
            console.log('Happy New Year!');
        }
    }

detonatorTimer(3);
```

Comment: you need to remove the console.log while calling the function that is console.log(detonatorTimer(3)); to be changed to just detonatorTimer(3)

Comment: Move the console.log inside of the if.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to improve a couple of things:

1. Log the `delay` conditionally
2. Use `else if` instead of just two `if`s
3. Remove the `console.log()` when invoking the function.

Try with this one:

```js
function detonatorTimer(delay) {
        if (delay > 0) {
          console.log(delay);
          delay --;
          setTimeout(detonatorTimer, 1000, delay);
        } else if(delay === 0) {
          console.log('Happy New Year!');
        }
    }
detonatorTimer(3);
```